# Saving API generated info to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to finish up my first ecommerce web site.  I am using ruby on rails and I have a select form populated by API calls to fedex and USPS.  It looks like this

```
<%= f.select :shipping_type, ship_hash.map {|k, v| [k, k]}%>
```

The hash comes from here

```
 <% ship_hash = {} %>
   <% @order_preview.fedex_rates.each do |rate| %>
        <% if rate.service_name == "FedEx Ground Home Delivery" || rate.service_name == "FedEx 2 Day" || rate.service_name == "FedEx Standard Overnight" %>
        <% ship_hash["#{rate.service_name}"] = ["#{number_to_currency(rate.price.to_f / 100)}"] %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
   <% @order_preview.usps_rates.each do |rate| %>
        <% if rate.service_name == "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day" %>
          <% ship_hash["#{rate.service_name}"] = ["#{number_to_currency(rate.price.to_f / 100)}"] %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I need to save both the shipping_type and the shipping_price into the DB.  I don't want to have two select forms (that wouldn't make sense, you could mix/match...)

Ideally I want a select form where it says the shipping_type, and then lists the price...and saves them both to their respective columns in my DB

I suppose I need something like

```
<%= f.select :shipping_type, ship_hash.map {|k, v| [k, k]}, :shipping_price, ship_hash.map {|k| [k, k]} %>
```

but that gets me

```
undefined method `merge' for :shipping_price:Symbol
```

I'm guessing it isn't possible to have both two different columns populating one select field, but I am pulling rates, and I want to have the user see both the shipping type in price in one dropdown menu, while splitting the parts up to different columns in the DB so I can use arithmetic later... does this make sense?

HItting a wall on this one, would appreciate the help.

Comment: please post full error

Comment: sure, I mean I'm not sure I should even be pursuing this... but one sec

Comment: Patrick, what about scraping these values once a day?

Comment: Well they change depending where the user ships them to... I think I need to read on 'scraping' though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using:

```
<select name="shipping_type">
```

Which have only one argument **(name = "shipping_type")**

But you should be using f.select. Something like this:

```
f.select :shipping_type, @your_model_to_be_selected.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
```

Edit:
Since you updated your question, now your problem seems to be saving more than one entry.

You have two options, you can have 2 selects, or you can, somehow, create a logic inside your `@your_model_to_be_selected.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }` that will represent both data.

Comment: can I have two :columns from one f.select tag? –

Comment: THanks for the response.  I would only want one select.  I'm not referencing a model with my hash.  I am referencing data I pulled from an API.  I would like to have both the key and value listed in the selection box.  Is this possible?

Comment: I already gave you the answer, man. You just need to use the hash that is comming from the API and transformed to whatever you like to be selected in the f.select method.